# Why does VSCode insert carriage return marked by ^M in gitt diff?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, newline, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lf

I'm running Ubuntu on WSL2 and VSCode on top of that. Although I have the "LF" setting on VSCode, whenever I save the file, VSCode insists on inserting a carriage return that gets marked as `^M` with `git diff`. Check it out:

```
diff --git a/network/outputs.tf b/network/outputs.tf
index e13366b..f7cc29c 100644
--- a/network/outputs.tf
+++ b/network/outputs.tf
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-output "vpc_id" {
-    description = "The ID of the Main VPC"
-    value       = aws_vpc.main.id
+output "vpc_id" {^M
+    description = "The ID of the Main VPC"^M
+    value       = aws_vpc.main.id^M
 }
```

I have no problem with this on VIM.

Comment: Have you installed VSCode inside WSL or on Windows ?

Comment: @Philippe To be honest, I don't remember exactly. What would be the best approach? I'm willing to uninstall and re-install to put an end to it.

Comment: I tend to install on Windows. Anyway, on git side, run `git config --list` and make sure `core.autocrlf=false`

Comment: @Philippe Thanks for your help, I've applied this config to global setting but unfortunately that wasn't enough to solve the issue, it still inserts a carriage return.

Comment: Can you do `dos2unix network/outputs.tf`, then use VSCode to edit and save it, then do `git diff` again ?

Comment: @Philippe yes that worked, it no longer has the `^M` mark

Comment: It proves that VSCode does not introduce ^M. Can you do this test : commit the file, remove the file from directory, then checkout, to see if it still has ^M ?

Answer (score 0):

If `git config --global core.autocrlf=false` is not enough, check if there is a `.gitattributes` rule ([typically `core.eol`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_effects)) which could influence how Git commit the file:

```
git check-attr --all -- network/outputs.tf
```

Comment: Thank you. I did this and still persisted. The `dox2unix` does the work, but looking for something that does it automatically.

Comment: @adriaanbd if that persists, it would be in your interest to dos2unix all the files, add, commit, and then checkout again to check that everything stays as is.